# Cannot change IPv6 Mode on my Airport Extreme (5th generation) using Ariport Utility 6

Tags: network, airport, ipv6

My provider recently added support for IPv6 and I wanted to configure it on my side. Unfortunately Airport Utility does not allow me to select appropriate IPv6 mode and I'm stuck with the tunnel mode which my provider does not support:

[image: Internet Options]

In this mode Airport Utility keeps telling me about "IPv6 Rely Error".

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is that Airport Extreme still does not support delegating IPv6 prefixes over PPPoE.